# Add a static library (.a file) to an Android project with CMake, get "CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target"

Tags: c, cmake, android-ndk, linker, static-libraries

I generate the static library from another Android project, so pretty sure they're useable.

I got four .a files based on CPU architectures, one .h file which also has been tested.

Now in new project, another .c file want to call the static library, i can't combine the two projects, the static libraries must be called in .a format.

I got "CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target", this is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(
    mylib
    STATIC
    src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libmylib.a
    src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libmylib.a
    src/main/jniLibs/x86/libmylib.a
    src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libmylib.a
)

target_link_libraries(
    native-lib
    mylib
)
```

mylib is the prebuilt library. native-lib want to call mylib.

A link about how to add .a file to a project from scrath is also welcome.

Comment: Try using `STATIC IMPORTED` maybe? See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt for an example.

Comment: For **link libraries** together, use `target_link_library` command; do not add one library as a source for another library. BTW, you may link only libraries for the same architecture. Linking `arm` and `x86` libraries is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_library(
        my_static_lib
        STATIC
        IMPORTED
)
set_target_properties(features PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmy_static_lib.a)
```

As you can see, i put those `.a` files in

`projectNmae\app\src\main\jniLibs\${ANDROID_ABI}\`,

if you change the location, remember to declare it in the `CMakeList.txt`.

I put `my_static_lib.h` in `src\main\include`, and use it in other `.c/cpp` file like:

```
#include "../include/features.h"
```

My **BIGGEST** mistake is the missed:

```
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
```

CMake cannot find **STATIC** library in locations like `src/main/app/native-lib.c`, **SHARED** library is OK, not **STATIC** library, which is very strange.

And **IMPORTED** is a must, i tried replace it with the whole location path, won't work.

Thank you all the comments and answers, i hope this answer can help newbies like me.

Answer (score 0):

You should link your existing **static** libs to your current **shared** library, i.e. `.so`. For example, you have  `src/c/dummy.c`. Then your `CMakeLists.txt` should be something like below:

```
add_library(my-shared-lib SHARED src/c/dummy.c)

target_link_libraries(my-shared-lib -Wl, --whole-archive src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmylib.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

**Explanations**

- `${ANDROID_ABI}` is the CMake variable to identify the current ABI being built, i.e. `arm64-v8a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_64`.